# How to page down a gridView or ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to have a button that can scroll all visible items (complete page) in a listView. I think the same will work for gridView.

I want solution for both, page up and page down.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int lastVisiblePosition = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();

scrollDown.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickListener(){
        public vod onClick(){
            listview.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listview.smoothScrollToPosition(lastVisiblePosition+1)
                }
            });
        }
    });

scrollUp.setOnClickListener(new setOnClickListener(){
        public vod onClick(){
            listview.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {         
                    listview.smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisiblePosition - (lastVisiblePosition - firstVisiblePosition));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: its not moving at all or it is moving to a wrong position?

Comment: wrong position. instead of smoothScrollToPosition, setSelection works better. but even with that, it jumps to wrong position. The reason i think is sometimes even when 5% of the last position item is visible, it is counted in  getLastVisiblePosition(), and hence it skips one or two rows.

Comment: Ohh. I don't think you can avoid this thing

Comment: sigh.. this should have been a builtin functionality, isn't it a common usecase !?